# Crow C++ framework HTML page is blank after compiling on Xcode

Tags: html, c++, xcode, web-frameworks, crow

After adding all the necessary header files from Crow, I finally managed to run and get the `Hello World` output at my localhost port. When I try to render a webpage using `mustache` command with a simple HTML file, the program compiles but I only get a blank page. Please help.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "crow.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

crow::SimpleApp app;
crow::mustache::set_base(".");

CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")([](){
    crow::mustache::context ctx;
    auto main_page = crow::mustache::load("site.html");
    return main_page.render();
});

app.port(18080)
//    .multithreaded()
.run();
return 0;
}
```

**site.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/ipkn/crow/issues/74

Answer (score 2):

Actially you can simply create folder called "template" and place there all of your  htmls and then load them by name.
This is official example: https://crowcpp.org/master/getting_started/a_simple_webpage/

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Crow was using Docker, and I had the same issue loading static files. To load the html, you cannot use a relative path, but instead must use an absolute path. For example, I had my main.cpp file in a folder called "server" and my index.html in a folder called "static". I initially said

```
auto main_page = crow::mustache::load("../static/index.html"); // "../" means go to parent folder
```

This did not work for me but you can go ahead and try it. Instead, I used the exact directory it was stored in my Docker container. "usr/src/web/mysite/static/index.html"

Comment: you can also try the chdir() command to change the directory to exactly where you need to be

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution is to render the static files using another server such as Node, and add CORS headers in the responses from C++ server using Crow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue. I replace `load` to `load_unsafe`.It works fine.